# Python3: Separating a text output into separate variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

I am working on a little project that requires detecting the properties of the computer it is running on. I am using the `os` module and the commmand `plat = os.uname` which gives me something like this: `posix.uname_result(sysname='Linux', nodename='abh57fbg', release='5.4.0-1009-gcp', version='#9-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 10 19:12:03 UTC 2020', machine="x86_64")`

What I am looking to do is parse this out and establish each of these results as their own variable that the rest of my code can act on. I did look through the official docs and do some searching, but I couldn't seem to find what I was looking for.

Comment: Did you read the `os.uname` documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have your `posix.uname_result` object you can access each value by it's property name. For example:

`print(plat.sysname)`

Should output:
`Linux`

Answer (score 1):

```py
info = os.uname()
attributes = ['sysname', 'nodename', 'release', 'version', 'root']
d = {attr : value for attr,value in zip(attributes, info)}
```

you can access individual attributes using :
`d[attr]`